# Microsoft R Server rxSpark Execution

Tags: microsoft-r

rxRemoteHadoopMRCall()
======  xxxx.cloudapp.azure.com (Master HPA Process) has started run at Sat Mar 18 08:15:43 2017  ======

17/03/18 03:16:36 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where application

Warning: libjvm.so not found in /log/cloudera/parcels/MRS-9.0.1/hadoop, searching system-wide

Internal Error: Cannot reset hdfs internal params while connected to an hdfs file system.

Error in try({ :
  Internal Error: Cannot reset hdfs internal params while connected to an hdfs file system.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if this is a problem with locating JRE. You can try setting `JAVA_HOME` for your user (`$HOME/.bashrc`) or for all users (`etc/environment`) on the node you're connecting to. It should point to a place that correctly resolves this path: `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so`